# Polyline dissapear when I zoom in closely - React JS

Tags: reactjs, path, leaflet, gis, polyline

The polyline is drawn well but when zooming in very close it disappears.

This is the code that draws the polyline:

```
import L from 'leaflet';

export const PortRoute = (mapRef, seaMetrixRoute) => {
  if (!mapRef || !seaMetrixRoute || !seaMetrixRoute.waypoints) {
    return;
  }

  const coordinatesArray = seaMetrixRoute.waypoints.map(waypoint => [
    waypoint.lat,
    waypoint.lon,
  ]); 

  const polyline = L.polyline(coordinatesArray, {
    color: 'yellow',
  })
    .addTo(mapRef.current)
    .bringToFront();

  mapRef.current.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
};
```

Thanks in advance.